# Fade transition element in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a nav bar in CSS. Currently when the user scrolls, my logo (`#cos_logo`) disappears immediately. I'd prefer if it just fades away slowly with a CSS transition.

Can someone explain how I achieve this with my existing code?

http://jsfiddle.net/78a2ro1r/

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header_nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

```css
#header_nav {
  background: #1588cb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
    height:1000px
}

nav {
    height:100px
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#header_nav{
    height:100px;
    transition: height .600s ease;
}

#header_nav.scrolled{
    height:78px;
}

#header_nav.scrolled ul#menu-primary-menu{
    bottom:45%;
}

#cos_logo {
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    float: right;
}

#header_nav.scrolled #cos_logo {
    display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_nav">

<a id="cos_logo" href="#" title=""><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=8&txt=171%C3%9730&w=171&h=30" alt="" width="171" height="30" class="no-scale" /></a>

<nav class="primary menu">

    <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
        
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
</nav>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery for the transition?

Comment: I'd like to, if I can :-) Can you explain how I would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t animate a display toggle in CSS as you can in JavaScript. Just use `opacity` here for this:

```
#cos_logo {
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

#header_nav.scrolled #cos_logo {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Demo:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/78a2ro1r/1/)

As an alternative you can use jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#cos_logo').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/78a2ro1r/3/)

Comment: Many thanks! If I was to use JS, how would I do this?

Comment: `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`, that's jQuery though. Also note that `opacity` will just toggle the opaqueness of the element, the literal element will be on your page unlike `display: none;`

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I updated my answer with an alternative jQuery method.

Comment: Many thanks! When I scroll back up, can it re-appear? :)

Comment: @KittMedia Thank you so much :)

Comment: You’re welcome. Would be great to see my answer as accepted then. ;)

Comment: @KittMedia Sorry, called away from computer, green ticked - many, many thanks :-)